# how to create a static template function to a pointer class?

Tags: c++, class, templates, static

My template class A contains a function that calls a static function of the template class:

```
template <typename T>
void A<T>::fun() {
    T obj = T::create();
    ....
}
```

How should I modify this if I want this code to work when T = B* ?
I know I can't do (*T)::create(), but conceptually, that is what I want.

Comment: To clarify: You want that code to work *both* when `T` is `U*` and when `T` is not a pointer type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [`std::remove_pointer`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_pointer) type trait:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
void A<T>::fun() {
    T obj = std::remove_pointer<T>::type::create();
//          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    // ...
}
```

Where both `std::remove_pointer<U*>::type` and `std::remove_pointer<U>::type` give `U`.